# Looking to accept user input, and calculate a running total - Swift 5/Xcode

Tags: ios, swift

I am a beginner working on an app that will function like a golf scorecard. My first issue has come while attempting to accept user input in a (prototype) series of 9 textFields so the user can type in their scores, and then a textView at the end that is not editable that will show the total for the 9 holes. I am trying to get this to be a running total that updates constantly.

I tried passing the inputs from each textField into an array, and returning the sum of the array to a the textView, but still had issues with the data type from the textField being a string, where as I will only be dealing with integers.

My clunky first pass is as follows -

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var holeOneScore: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var holeTwoScore: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var holeThreeScore: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var holeFourScore: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var holeFiveScore: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var holeSixScore: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var holeSevenScore: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var holeEightScore: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var holeNineScore: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var totalForFrontNine: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

//MARK: Calculate Scores

    @IBAction func calculate(_ sender: Any) {

        let hole1:Int = Int(holeOneScore.text!)!
        let hole2:Int = Int(holeTwoScore.text!)!
        let hole3:Int = Int(holeThreeScore.text!)!
        let hole4:Int = Int(holeFourScore.text!)!
        let hole5:Int = Int(holeFiveScore.text!)!
        let hole6:Int = Int(holeSixScore.text!)!
        let hole7:Int = Int(holeSevenScore.text!)!
        let hole8:Int = Int(holeEightScore.text!)!
        let hole9:Int = Int(holeNineScore.text!)!

        let totalArray = [hole1, hole2, hole3, hole4, hole5, hole6, hole7, hole8, hole9]
        let totalScore = totalArray.reduce(0, +)

        totalForFrontNine.text = String(totalScore)
        print(totalForFrontNine!)


    }
```

It worked, but barely. Any thoughts to modify this or a complete refresh is fine! I am not tied to anything as i am using this project to just teach me the basics.

Thanks in advance, cheers - glassGarrett

Comment: use IBOutletCollection ... instead of single entity ... this will conclude your code in just 4-5 lines .... search IBOutlet collection

Answer (score 0):

Like @jawadali mentioned, use `IBOutletCollection`. Here is a [tutorial](https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/what-is-an-iboutletcollection-in-ios-78cfbc4080a1) about how to use it.

As for the other issue,

> ...the data type from the textField being a string, where as I will only be dealing with integers.

A quick solution is to set the `keyboardType` of your textfield to `UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad`, or `.numberPad` in Swift.

```swift
textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
```

Or in storyboard,

[image]